# How does one expose constants in a java google app engine Endpoints API?

Tags: google-cloud-endpoints, google-app-engine

Simple question -- how do you expose constants in a java google app engine Endpoints API?
e.g

```
public static final int CODE_FOO = 3845;
```

I'd like the client of the Endpoints to be able to match on CODE_FOO rather than on 3845. I'll end up doing enum wrappers (which probably is better anyway) but I'm just starting to be curious if this is even doable? Thx

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "match on" ? What exactly do you want the client and the server to do with this constant ?

Comment: say server returns a ResultCode which is a simple int holder.

client needs to match on the returned int to decipher the meaning, vi a switch statement or a series of if/else


if(resultcode.getCode == FooApi.OK_CODE) //


if(resultcode.getCode == FooApi.BAR_CODE) // etc

Comment: Then why don't you return a String/Enum ?

Comment: ok say i return a String, what do i compare it against? do i hardcode the string literally that represents "OK" on both sides? that's not good. I'd like to the client to get the "OK" string constant from the endpoints API. Does that make sense?

Comment: and ya as i pointed out above enum is better because it's a dedicated type that can have a meaning, but i'm curious in general. Can we export constants from endpoint APIs or only methods?

Comment: actually just tried returning an enum inside the ResultHolder and that gets converted into a String by the framework too, so my question very much stands. David, if my question does not make sense, I'd be happy to update my original post with some code to illustrate. It's also possible I'm missing something...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that this isn't a full answer but here is a workaround: in Android Studio, create a very light-weight "common" java project and shove anything you want to keep in sync there such as constants as well as common types that you want exposed (e.g. an enum representing all possible return / error codes, etc).

This way you should get pretty decent compiler-time safety and keep these guys in sync.

Please feel free to comment if anyone has better suggestions.

Answer (score -1):

This is unfortunately a **Law of Information** (ahem). If you have a message protocol you defined, both sides of the interaction need to be aware of the messages that could be passed. There's no other way for the client to be aware of what it needs to respond to. Ajax libraries hard-code the number "200" to be able to detect a successful request, as one example.

Yes, just use a switch statement on strings inside your client code. Or, you could use a dictionary of strings pointing to functions and just call the function after de-referencing the dictionary given the string you got.

Comment: there has to be a way to expose a constant though, which gets compiled into the client library as a result of compiling the backend

that coupling already exists in the form of the Endpoints API -- however, it appears it only supports classes, i see no technical limitation not to be able to expose constants

am i making sense? thx

Comment: A little bit. I understand that this "could be done" in terms of embedding these constant strings/numbers inside the client library that is generated (or in the case of the JS client, dynamically-created when the `load()` function is called), I don't think it would help at all, and this is why: the constants need to be addressed somehow. What will their variable names be?

Comment: same name that you pick on the backend, just like the name you pick for any of the many classes in Endpoints. That coupling is significantly lower risk than the coupling of hardoding the VALUE of the constant. If I choose to name something OK_CODE in backend and assign it to "10" and tomorow decide to reassign it to "100" -- yes I need to update the backend and recompile the frontend with it, but that's a given anyway. I don't need to truly do anything on the front end outside of that always-needed step. And if I choose to rename OK_RESULT to RESULT_OK i am also safe

Comment: This is the reason enums were invented - so that programmers could use meaningful variable names that map to unique values in the programming language, so they won't be confused with one another. You still need to type the names, though, and I don't think that's much of an improvement over just raw strings. You could always include an API method that lists all possible special response strings, but the client would "already" need to know about these, in order to implement behaviour that corresponds to them.

Comment: as it will cause a compile break. Deciding on what we call constants that represent our protocols is significantly better than hardcoding their values. That is a pretty basic thing I think :)

Comment: Anonymous4444: Refactoring the references to "raw strings" littered throughout the code base to a single constant is a HUGE and very basic improvement. I'm not sure I should be arguing its merits, and frankly, you should really not be questioning them either.

Yes, I readily agree that enums would be better but they are absolutely not supported by Endpoints so I'm just asking for Int or String constants which are STILL better than using the raw values throughout both codebases (front & backend) without capturing them in constants...

Comment: I'm not sure why you would want to change the arbitrary value from 10 to 100... you see what I mean? Whether it's a switch statement on raw strings, or a switch statement on strings that are mapped-to in the client library by pre-populated variable-names based on the API's defined "constants", it will be the difference between

`case: "special_enum_value_operation_create"` and 

`case: gapi.myAPI.constants.special_enum_value_operation_create`

Comment: because it might happen, because refactorings happen unexpectedly, and every single time I've said in any non-trivial project "this will never happen" it has. And because 6 months from now and 10x the lines of code i have today this MIGHT become a problem and i don't want to have to think about it and remember (how on earth will you search for this reliably?)

Comment: This is a fundamental technique of mitigating refactoring risk and improving code maintainability and reducing risk of bugs.

Now if you do not agree with me, you are perfectly entitiled not to! But we will just have to agree to disagree that this hardcoding the values is a terrible practice. :) Thanks for taking the time to answer, however.

Comment: Any IDE, most text editors, or the `sed` command can be used to replace either the string `"OK_RESULT"` to `"RESULT_OK"`, or the symbol `OK_RESULT` to `RESULT_OK` across your entire codebase. While "unexpected things happen" and "plan for mutability" are great mantras, it seems an over-reaction to worry about you changing your own custom message protocol, and also being unable to know where the places are that you need to reflect the change...

Comment: If you're envisioning that defining an enum of constants in your endpoints API, it's unclear how you are expecting to reference these constants in your client code? If you are going to use the pattern `gapi.myAPI.constants.RESULT_OK`, based on generation done by the endpoints magically, you would be "hard-coding" that symbol (`gapi.myAPI.constants.RESULT_OK`) anywhere it needs to be referenced. Changing whether it points to 1, 2, 3, or 1337 behind the scenes is immaterial. Given this stability in the symbol, which you have no problem with refactoring, why would a string be worse?

Comment: Also, I'm just having fun discussing this with you, but I feel we should cut it short or move to chat. If you have a feature request to make for App Engine, you should go to their public issue tracker and try to be as descriptive as possible.

Comment: I think you continue not to get my point and you just repeated what you said at first. I think we won't go any further with this. I respect your effort to help me here but we will just agree to disagree. The renaming of RESULT_OK to OK_RESULT is only a very minor benefit which I mentioned to preempt any questoins on your point. The crux of the benefit is not hardcoding strings and numbers everywhere, but hardcoding constants. If you insist that hardcoding a value rather than a constant is equivalent and buys you nothing, we will not agree here. :)

Comment: The oft-quoted advice on hard-coding constants only applies when the *value* behind the constant symbol matters. When you have an app that needs to shard to 4 instances, you would put `SHARD_COUNT = 4`, with the understanding that even this constant may some day change, but it's a nice pattern for now and also then.

In your case, you asked about symbols where the value doesn't matter. The name of the variable itself communicates the meaning. This is why it's insignificant to use a symbol or a string (*"I'd like the client of the Endpoints to be able to match on CODE_FOO rather than on 3845"*)

Comment: I get your point, really i do. And I still disagree. It is not just the benefit of changing the value though that is a big one.  What if you want to change the pattern and introduce a deeper level of indirection or stronger types. The constant served as much more than merely a placeholder, it is already an abstraction in its simplest form with a myriad of benefits. This is just one example. We will not agree here. I am not saying your suggestion is wrong but i am saying it is not ideal.